# How to initialize UserControl's ComboBox from the MainView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, user-controls

I have a UserControl wrote in WPF which implements "SerialPort" class from "System.IO.Ports" and it contains some Buttons and a ComboBox.

It has some code behind functions to open port, close port and get all ports available from the PC.

Here is part of my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Choose COM:"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="10,0"/>
        <ComboBox Name="ComboBoxPorts"
                  Height="25"
                  Width="80" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Also in the code behind of this XAML I have function which works, that get all the ports from the PC, and should fill my ComboBox with the COM ports available.

EDIT:

```
public partial class Communication : UserControl
{
    public SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Ports
    {
        get
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<String>)GetValue(OCProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(OCProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public Communication()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    public void GetPortNames()
    {
        int num;
        this.ports = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        string[] port_Names = SerialPort.GetPortNames().OrderBy(a => a.Length > 3 && int.TryParse(a.Substring(3), out num) ? num : 0).ToArray();

        foreach (string port in port_Names)
            this.ports.Add(port);
        this.DataContext = this;
        ComboBoxPorts.ItemsSource = this.ports;
        ComboBoxPorts.SelectedItem = this.ports.FirstOrDefault(); // object to show on comboBox
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty OCProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Ports", typeof(ObservableCollection<String>), typeof(Communication));
```

In my MainWindow I call to that UserControl element, and then after the window loaded, the ComboBox still empty without any strings in it.
How I can make that I'll see the COM ports in my ComboBox which defined in my UserControl?

Main Window Code:

EDIT:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

My MainWindow XAML:

EDIT:

```
<Window x:Class="MyLabratory.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:MyProject ="clr-namespace:MyLabratory"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <MyProject:Communication />
</Grid>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: no items is showing in the ComboBox. when you opened it the list is empty.

Comment: are you familiar with binding? are you willing to go for it?

Comment: yes, I uses sometimes with bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you should have used, `MVVM` pattern for you project and instead of doing all your logic like getting the port name and filling `ComboBox` should have been done from your view model.

For your case, use following code:

```
public partial class Communication : UserControl
{
    public SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Ports {get;set;}

    public Communication()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    public void GetPortNames()
    {
        int num;
        this.Ports= new ObservableCollection<string>();
        string[] port_Names = SerialPort.GetPortNames().OrderBy(a => a.Length > 3 && int.TryParse(a.Substring(3), out num) ? num : 0).ToArray();

        foreach (string port in port_Names)
            this.Ports.Add(port);
        this.DataContext=this;
        ComboBoxPorts.ItemsSource = this.Ports;
        ComboBoxPorts.SelectedItem = this.Ports.FirstOrDefault(); // object to show on comboBox
    }
}
```

Create a property of type `ObservableCollection<string>` which will work as items source for your `ComboBox`. UI gets updated when an item is added to /removed from an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Nitin - I tried your code, it is still not working. I add DependancyProperty in that class, but still didn't use it. I have EDITED my original post

Comment: Why have you created a `DependencyProperty`? I don't see a call to `GetPortNames()` method from anywhere in your code. Adding your user control in XAML doesn't mean that it will call the method itself. Call `GetPortNames()` method from the constructor of either `Communication` class or `MainWindow` class (In both case after `InitializeComponent()` method)

Comment: You right. I firstly called it from the MainWindow constructor and it doesn't worked, now I called it from Communication's InitializeComponent() method and ITS WORKS!!

Comment: If it worked, then please don't forget to mark my post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the user control to the visual tree, you just instantiated it but you then also need to add to a layout control, like a `Grid`.

Instead of creating the control programmatically:

```
Communication communicator = new Communication();
```

I would create it in Xaml:

```
<Communication Name="communicator"/>
```

Comment: In my MainWindow XAML? if yes, then where exactly?

Comment: yes in your MainWindow XAML, where exactly to insert it, I can't decide for you